# Can we revert a last git pull on my local machine only?

Tags: git, github, local, revert

I have pulled data from a shared repository, but seems to be some errors on the remote. I can not fix his errors and commit back the code. I want to revert my code before pull and work on the feature on which I was working on.

Doing only `git revert sha` will work? I don't want to push my revert to the server.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git revert` generates a new commit. Try to `git reset --hard sha` where `sha` is the commit id of your last working commit.

That will reset your `HEAD` to that commit and so deletes all following commits, which should be the commits you just pulled.

Caution: Can cause data loss on wrong usage.

Comment: Note that `git reset --hard` will delete any uncomitted changes.

Comment: @phortx / @ikke : This is my git status
`$ git status 
# On branch develop
nothing to commit, working directory clean`

I think there would have no any loss, right?

Comment: Then it's no problem. To be sure, just copy your directory ;)